# I want to make it so when i have jumped once with right click in the air, i can't do it again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this problem that i want to make it so when i right click in the air once (as an extra jump)(after jumping with space) i can't do it again.

here is my current movement script:

```
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 8f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && isGrounded == false)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 4f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my current "Grounded" script

```
public class Grounded : MonoBehaviour

    {
    GameObject Player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Player = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Move2D>().isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i followed this script on youtube. Please answer if i need to provide more information for future post. I am very new to coding.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make it easier for others to answer the question, could you please tag it with the correct context? For example, it looks like this is Unity but I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, check out https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to do in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have `isGrounded` to prevent a double-tap of your jump key (space I think you said), and that logic would be simple enough to extend to work to prevent a double-boost:

- add a new global variable `isBoosted` (add it under `isGrounded`);
- when you jump, as well as adding some momentum to your mob, also set `isBoosted` to false;
- when you right-click for a second jump check that `isBoosted` is false;
- inside the code for the right-click, set `isBoosted` to true, as well as adding yet more momentum to your model.

The first time you boost you will set `isBoosted` to true, the second time you attempt to boost it will fail, as the test for `isBoosted` being false will fail.  When you hit the ground, and use space to jump again, it will reset, so allowing you a new boost every time you "reset".

Is this the "best" way to do it?  Probably not, but it's consistent with what you already have...

Comment: Thank you :D That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First always store references to not do unnecessary work!

Then I would go the other way round:

- The grounded script only knows whether it is grounded or not.
- The Move2D actively asks for this value and doesn't get it set from somewhere else "magically".

In your grounded script I would only have

```
public class Grounded : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Read-only public property
    public bool IsGrounded { get; private set; }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // Note: Rather use CompareTag instead of == !
        // it is not only faster but also secure against typos. 
        // == would fail silently while CompareTag throws an exception 
        // indicating that you passed an invalid tag
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            IsGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            IsGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then if I understand correctly you could add one simple bool flag `CanDoubleJump` which is only available **once** after a jump and is reset to false after it was used. So the Move2D could look like

```
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Already reference this via drag&drop in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    // I would also go this way round and let the Move2D script
    // actively check for the value instead of getting it set from somewhere else
    [SerializeField] private Grounded _grounded;

    // As fallback get it once on runtime
    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if(!_grounded) _grounded = GetComponentInChildren<Grounded>(true);
    }


    private bool CanDoubleJump;

    private void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        // Note instead of going through the transform which breaks the Physics
        // I would rather simply set the velocity and let the Rigidbody itself handle the rest
        _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        // Checking the bool flag is cheaper so do it first
        if (_grounded.IsGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * 8f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            CanDoubleJump = true;
        }
        // I would add else since anyway both can't be true at the same time
        else if (CanDoubleJump && !_grounded.IsGrounded && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * 4f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            CanDoubleJump = false;
        }
        // Reset the flag if it wasn't used just in case
        else if(_grounded.IsGrounded)
        {
            CanDoubleJump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try it :)